# Get device tree node properties from tty_struct structure

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

Is it possible to get device tree node properties of a tty device from its tty_struct structure?

The goal would be to retrieve some custom properties of the serial port from the device tree and use them in a line discipline that I'm going to link to the serial port.

This is the device tree node of the uart I'm using.

```
uart2: serial@021e8000 {
    compatible = "fsl,imx6q-uart", "fsl,imx21-uart";
    reg = <0x021e8000 0x4000>;
    interrupts = <0 27 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    clocks = <&clks IMX6QDL_CLK_UART_IPG>,
         <&clks IMX6QDL_CLK_UART_SERIAL>;
    clock-names = "ipg", "per";
    dmas = <&sdma 27 4 0>, <&sdma 28 4 0>;
    dma-names = "rx", "tx";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart2>;
    status = "okay";

    master = <0>;
    baudrate = 9600;
};
```

This is part of the c code in the line discipline I'm working on.

```
static struct tty_ldisc_ops my_ldisc = {
    .owner      = THIS_MODULE,
    .magic      = TTY_LDISC_MAGIC,
    .name       = "custom_ldisc",
    .open       = my_ldisc_open,
    ...
};

static int my_ldisc_open(struct tty_struct *tty)
{
    // here I would like to access "master" and
    // "baudrate" properties
}
```

Using ldattach on ttymxc1 (tty device on uart2) with my_ldisc as discipline,
my_ldisc_open() is called, but the parameter *tty seems to have no references
to the uart2 device tree node.

Comment: The tty device should appear as struct tty_port, so that's more likely place to hold that info.

Comment: Actually the open function of the line discipline is called by the tty module only with a tty_struct as parameter. So this is the struct I have to use. But I don't find any reference to the device tree in this structure. Tried with tty->dev->of_node, tty->dev->platform_data and tty->dev->fwnode, but they're all null pointers.

Comment: tty->port should give you port

Comment: But tty->port seems to have no reference to the device tree node of the serial port.

Comment: Can you share the relevant portion from the dts?

Comment: See my edit to the question.

Comment: *tty* is a parent or a child (don’t remember by heart) of the real device.

Comment: Regarding to the question is a whole, you are trying to do something wrong. The properties are read at *->probe()* time, and *baudrate* one looks suspicious, since termios can and do change it when tty is starting.